# Oracle: how to put value in a variable from a SQL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to use the total number of records in a table in a variable of data type number, but I am not able to do this if I use the following statement :

```
row_num number;
row_num := select count(*) from emp;
```

I am trying to use this in a procedure .. what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is inside a PL/SQL procedure, the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO row_num FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable and follow the query to copy count to a variable

```
DECLARE row_num NUMBER(10) := 0;

select count(*) into row_num from emp;
```

Comment: No need to initialise the variable, I think. Count always returns an integer greater then or equal to zero, and a projection that consists only of aggregate functions always returns a single row  in the absence of a group by clause